# How to use Matc tool from google filament

Tags: google-filament

I was reading through the filament documentation and they give the comamnd to out .mat files from the jsonish material definition like this :

```
matc --reflect parameters filament/src/materials/skybox.mat
```

I have two questions, how do I install this matc tool and after making the .mat file, how do I reference it to make the renderablemesh use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matc` is the material compiler tool which you have to download from the filament repository release [page](https://github.com/google/filament/releases).

1. Download the archive for your operating system. If your os is window
   then download the [window variation](https://github.com/google/filament/releases/download/v1.30.0/filament-v1.30.0-windows.tgz).
2. Extract the archive wherever you want.
3. Go to the bin folder inside it.
4. Paste the .mat file
5. Run the command:  `matc -p mobile -a opengl -o baked_color.filamat baked_color.mat`. This command is building for
   `mobile` platform and `opengl` as graphics engine where input file is
   `baked_color.mat` and the output file is `baked_color.filamat`.

To know more about `matc` commands, visit [this site](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man1/matc.1.html).